How to efficiently handle large datasets in Python using Pandas?
I am working with a large dataset (approximately 1 million rows) in Python using the Pandas library, and I am experiencing performance issues when performing operations such as filtering and aggregating data.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('large_dataset.csv')

# Example operation: Filtering and aggregating
result = df[df['column_name'] > threshold_value].groupby('another_column').mean()


I've tried using df.memory_usage(deep=True) to analyze memory usage and pd.read_csv() with the chunksize parameter to load the data in chunks, but I still face slow performance.
**What are some best practices for optimizing data processing with Pandas for large datasets?
**
Any suggestions on techniques, alternative libraries, or specific functions that could help improve performance would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:
Memory Analysis: I used df.memory_usage(deep=True) to understand memory consumption and found that certain columns were using a lot of memory due to their data types.

Loading Data in Chunks: I attempted to load the dataset in chunks using the chunksize parameter with pd.read_csv(). This allowed me to work with smaller parts of the dataset, but my filtering and aggregation operations remained slow.

Data Type Optimization: I experimented with changing data types of certain columns to more memory-efficient types (e.g., converting float64 to float32), which helped reduce memory usage but didn’t significantly improve the processing time.

What I Was Expecting: I expected that by analyzing memory usage and optimizing data types, along with loading data in chunks, I would see a noticeable improvement in the speed of my filtering and aggregation operations. However, the performance remains suboptimal, especially with the large size of the dataset.



For the particular operations you're looking at, it seems like the computation is parallelizable. You can use the multiprocessing module to get aggregate counts and means for each "chunk", then use those results to get overall means for each group

You might also want to consider using Numba

@BenGrossmann Multiprocessing (with Pandas) is generally slow due to inter-process communication. This is especially true here regarding the target operations. For example, it is faster to filter things serially than copy the whole dataframe on workers so to filter lines, especially if most of them are filtered out... As for multithreading, it is useless due to the GIL (unless released). (C)Python parallelism sucks for that...

i recommend you take a look at parquet , integrates well (seamless) with csv and pandas, is performant, good compression rates.

We need more information to really help you (without wild guesses). Can you provide an example of (realistic) dataframe so we can: know the number of columns, they types and the distribution of probability of the values? The later is especially important so to know the probability of df['column_name'] > threshold_value to be true (number of filtered lines). We can also use that so to profile the code and know if the proposed solution is faster or not.

You said you wanted to improve slow performance, but most of your attention is focused on memory usage. Is there a reason for this? Like running out of RAM?

no one mentioned it, so I will mention polars package. You can do problematic operations there (faster, with less RAM) and then convert result to pandas if needed. A bit steep learning curve at start, but worth it. Example problem you have should be easy to solve with google/ai

It's difficult to say what exactly is the bottleneck without having access to the current file, columns and types (eg. dtypes) and memory usage statistics and profiles. But we can at least consider some options.
Toy dataset with 1M rows
First lets create some dummy dataset to illustrate some key points:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import duckdb as db

N = 1_000_000

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "c": np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c"], size=N),
    "x": np.random.uniform(size=N),
    "y": np.random.normal(size=N)
})

data.to_csv("blob.csv")  # File is about 45 Mb
data.memory_usage()      # Memory fingerprint is about 22 Mb

Therefore 1M rows with 3 columns of interest should be bearable. Creating a subset of columns will reduce your memory fingerprint to some acceptable amount.
Explicitly select columns you want to aggregate
Now we will perform the aggregation as you suggested:
%timeit -r 10 -n 10
data[data["x"] > 0.5].groupby("c")["y"].mean()
# 137 ms ± 11.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

Notice the indexation ["y"] on specific columns before aggregation to prevent means to apply on all columns left by the group by operation. Indexing will reduce the volumetry of the answer and the intensity of computation.
Alternative to pandas
There is a nice package called duckdb that allow to perform such operation on large dataset while limiting footprint wrt pandas.
The equivalent query can then be stated in SQL directly from the CSV file:
%timeit -r 10 -n 10
db.query("SELECT c, MEAN(y) FROM blob.csv WHERE x > 0.5 GROUP BY c;") 
# 89.3 ms ± 1.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10 loops each)

Going further
Don't hesitate to provide give us more grain to grind (reference dataset, link to file, file sample, dtypes, actual statistics and profiles) in order to reproduce your issue.

for info ....
using a subset of NYC taxi data  (yellow_tripdata_2009-10) (1.5million rows) (which perversely for this is already in parquet format ... so rolled that back to a csv for this exercise and took 1.5million rows from tha)
I didn't try any aggregation, this was merely to show a potential alternative
# Convert CSV to Parquet
timerS=timer()
df = pd.read_csv(csvFile)
timerE=timer()
print( 'csv to df:', timerE - timerS)
timerS=timer()
df.to_parquet(pFile, engine='pyarrow')
timerE=timer()
print( 'df to parquet:', timerE - timerS)

csv to df: 49.38248022104381
df to parquet: 33.50898619799409

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1499999 entries, 0 to 1499998
Data columns (total 19 columns):
 #   Column                 Non-Null Count    Dtype  
---  ------                 --------------    -----  
 0   Unnamed: 0             1499999 non-null  int64  
 1   vendor_name            1499999 non-null  object 
 2   Trip_Pickup_DateTime   1499999 non-null  object 
 3   Trip_Dropoff_DateTime  1499999 non-null  object 
 4   Passenger_Count        1499999 non-null  int64  
 5   Trip_Distance          1499999 non-null  float64
 6   Start_Lon              1499999 non-null  float64
 7   Start_Lat              1499999 non-null  float64
 8   Rate_Code              0 non-null        float64
 9   store_and_forward      673295 non-null   float64
 10  End_Lon                1499999 non-null  float64
 11  End_Lat                1499999 non-null  float64
 12  Payment_Type           1499999 non-null  object 
 13  Fare_Amt               1499999 non-null  float64
 14  surcharge              1499999 non-null  float64
 15  mta_tax                283086 non-null   float64
 16  Tip_Amt                1499999 non-null  float64
 17  Tolls_Amt              1499999 non-null  float64
 18  Total_Amt              1499999 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(13), int64(2), object(4)
memory usage: 217.4+ MB


#
# file size substantially reduced
#
ll -tralh yellow_tripdata_2009-10.*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester 198M Oct  1 00:07 yellow_tripdata_2009-10.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tester tester  57M Oct  1 00:44 yellow_tripdata_2009-10.parquet



The OP problem is the filtering and aggregating while your answer does not address this (but shows how to load the dataframe faster). To quote the OP: "filtering and aggregation operations remained slow".

The suggestion to convert the to parquet was to see if there was any performance advantage gains in using parquet's columnar storage, compression and (potential) memory usage and for the OP to time their aggregation ops on that. As the OP had not supplied any data or supporting schema it would be fruitless to show aggregation based on a dataset that bares no resemblance to the OP's.

Pandas has its own in-memory representation internally which mainly relies on basic Numpy arrays. It is independent of how the file is loaded. Thus, changing the way the file is loaded should have no impact on computation (which is the problem of the OP). It is still an interesting improvement but better as a comment (like you did). Regarding data, I agree, and this is why we should add a comment requesting a MRE instead of providing an answer based on missing important information.

If you have already optimized by using better dtypes and ensured that every function is really vectorized (so not apply or np.vectorize which are syntactic sugar), you can work on your chunks.
Indeed, as already said by other comments, if you have chunks, if should be possible to parallelize.
Personally, I prefer using joblib for that instead of standard lib features : easier and more flexible.
Then, numba can also help and, obviously, but more complex… cython

You can reduce memory usage by changing the datatypes.

change to categorical types
change to smaller datatypes just like you mentioned, convert float64 to float32 or int64 to int32 where possible but there might be some precision loss.

Also there is a extend function from pandas -- Dask, which provides parallel computing library for larger datasets by splitting data into chunks and parallelizing operations.

The OP explicitly stated this has been done and did not fix the problem. Here is a quote from the OP: "Data Type Optimization: I experimented with changing data types of certain columns to more memory-efficient types (e.g., converting float64 to float32), which helped reduce memory usage but didn’t significantly improve the processing time.".
